# Extracting a series of URL using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I just trying to run through a list of url link, but it keep showing run time error'91',object variable or with block variable not set.

The data I want to extract is from iframes. It do shown some of the values but it stuck in the middle of process with error.

Below is the sample url link that I want to extract value from:http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5927201

```
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer As Object
    With IE
        .Visible = False

        For u = 2 To 100

        .navigate Cells(u, 1).Value

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend



        With .document.getElementById("bm_ann_detail_iframe").contentDocument
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 3) = .getElementById("main").innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 4) = .getElementsByClassName("company_name")(0).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 5) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(0).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 6) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(5).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 7) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(7).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 8) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(8).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 9) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(9).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 10) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(10).innerText
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(u, 11) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(11).innerText
       End With

    Next u
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line is the error occuring and is there a particular URL that is failing? Can you provide some of these URLs?

Comment: This line is incorrect:  Dim IE As New InternetExplorer As Object It should be either  Dim IE As New InternetExplorer   or  Dim IE As Object. As you don't use a Set statement to instantiate the object I am guessing you are auto-instantiating with early bound version i.e.  Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

Comment: Your error is because the last index for that class  via the iframe is   9 i.e. ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(u, 9) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(9).innerText  .   10 and 11 are invalid.

Comment: What are the exact values you want please from the page? Supplying some sample URLs (working and failing)  will help give some indication if there are the same number of elements with that class in the iframe across each URL.  If all fail then it may simply be wrong indexing.

Comment: Hi QHarr, thank you for your reply. Firstly I am trying to extract all the link from the webpage and filter out all the specific link that I need. Using the url link that I filtered out, I would like to extract some specific data from the iframes. The code above refer to my second step of extracting the data from iframes. But now I am facing some error during my first step. I would open another new thread before solving these question. Really appreciate for your reply. Thank

Comment: I am a little confused.  What are you trying to get from the iframe please? Which specific items? For example, in the URL provided http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5927201

Comment: For example:http://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/viewHtml?e=2892907#http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5928057, i would like to get the name,number of securities acquired.Because my job everyday have to summarize all the announcement, who is buying or selling the shares. So I have to open numerous web tab, and copy all the data and paste into excel. I am thinking to automate all these process using VBA.

Comment: So, with [this](http://disclosure.bursamalaysia.com/FileAccess/viewHtml?e=2892907#http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5928057) there are 3 changes detailed each with their own details and a summary table underneath. Which is needed? This page has more  _results_ than your other page which is why using fixed indexing isn't working across pages. It looks like you might need to potentially handle retrieving specific rows from results tables.

Comment: ya,that is another problem I am facing now. Because there are two main changes which is acquisition and disposal. The end result that I need is the net changes, which I may need to sum them up accordingly.

Comment: Is that not what the _summary_ (?) bottom table is?

Comment: no, the bottom table does not sum it up, I need to sum it up by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Your error is due to the fact there are different numbers of elements for the given class name depending on the results per page. So you can't used fixed indexes. For the page you indicated the last index for that class, via the iframe, is 9 i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(u, 9) = .getElementsByClassName("formContentData")(9).innerText` . 10 and 11 are invalid. Below I show a way to determine the number of results and extract info from each result row.

### **General principle:**

Ok... so the following works on the principle of targeting the `Details of Changes` table for most of the info.

**Example extract:**

[image]

More specifically, I target the rows that repeat the info for `No, Date of Change, #Securities, Type of Transaction and Nature of Interest`. These values are stored in an array of arrays (one array per row of information). Then the results arrays are stored in a collection to later be written out to the sheet. I loop each table cell in the targeted rows (`td` tag elements within parent `tr`) to populate the arrays.

I add in the `Name` from the table above on the page and also, because there can be more than one row of results, depending on the webpage, and because I am writing the results to a new `Results` sheet, I add in the `URL` before each result to indicate source of information.

---

**TODO:**

1. Refactor the code to be more modular
2. Potentially add in some error handling

---

### CSS selectors:

---

① I select the `Name` element, which I refer to as `title`, from the `Particulars of substantial Securities Holder` table.

**Example name element:**

> [image]

Inspecting the HTML for this element shows it has a class of `formContentLabel`, and that it is the first class with this value on the page.

**Example HTML for target Name:**

> [image]

This means I can use a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) , `.formContentLabel`,   to target the element. As it is a single element I want I use the `querySelector` method to apply the CSS selector.

---

② I target the rows of interest in the `Details of Changes` table with a selector combination of `.ven_table tr`. This is [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) combination combining selecting elements with `tr` tag having parent with class `ven_table`.  As these are multiple elements I use the `querySelectorAll` method to apply the CSS selector combination.

**Example of a target row:**

> [image]

---

**Example results returned by CSS selector (sample):**

[image]

The rows I am interested start at 1 and repeat every + 4 rows after e.g. row 5 , 9 etc.
So I use a little maths in the code to return just the rows of interest:

```
Set currentRow = data.item(i * 4 + 1)
```

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, headers(), u As Long, resultCollection As Collection
    headers = Array("URL", "Name", "No", "Date of change", "# Securities", "Type of Transaction", "Nature of Interest")
    Set resultCollection = New Collection
    Dim links()
    links = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A3")) 'A100

    With IE
        .Visible = True

        For u = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
            If InStr(links(u), "http") > 0 Then
                .navigate links(u)

                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) '<you may not always need this. Or may need to increase.
                Dim data As Object, title As Object
                With .document.getElementById("bm_ann_detail_iframe").contentDocument
                    Set title = .querySelector(".formContentData")
                    Set data = .querySelectorAll(".ven_table tr")
                End With

                Dim results(), numberOfRows As Long, i As Long, currentRow As Object, td As Object, c As Long, r As Long

                numberOfRows = Round(data.Length / 4, 0)
                ReDim results(1 To numberOfRows, 1 To 7)

                For i = 0 To numberOfRows - 1
                    r = i + 1
                    results(r, 1) = links(u): results(r, 2) = title.innerText
                    Set currentRow = data.item(i * 4 + 1)
                    c = 3
                    For Each td In currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
                        results(r, c) = Replace$(td.innerText, "document.write(rownum++);", vbNullString)
                        c = c + 1
                    Next td
                Next i
                resultCollection.Add results
                Set data = Nothing: Set title = Nothing
            End If
        Next u
        .Quit
    End With
    Dim ws As Worksheet, item As Long
    If Not resultCollection.Count > 0 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Evaluate("ISREF('Results'!A1)") Then '<==Credit to @Rory for this test
        Set ws = Worksheets.Add
        ws.NAME = "Results"
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
        ws.cells.Clear
    End If

    Dim outputRow As Long: outputRow = 2
    With ws
        .cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        For item = 1 To resultCollection.Count
            Dim arr()
            arr = resultCollection(item)
            For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
                .cells(outputRow, 1).Resize(1, 7) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, i, 0)
                outputRow = outputRow + 1
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Example results using 2 provided tests URLs:**

[image]

---

**Sample URLs in sheet1:**

1. http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5928057
2. http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/listed-companies/company-announcements/5927201

Comment: Hi QHarr, I facing "run time error -2147467259(80004005):automation error unspecified error", I am using the sample url and put it onto RANGE(a2:A3)

Comment: But if i just input one url onto cell A2, the code run well

Comment: Strangely I now get that when I didn't before but only if I run without a pause. 
 If I pause at the error and press run again it is fine. Give me a second to explore.

Comment: So I added a 1 sec wait and it worked fine. While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

Comment: I added Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) after While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend , but i only can get the data from first url link

Comment: ya, your files work fines for me, i wonder is that because your file type is binary while mine one is macro-enabled.Thank

Comment: No. Binary are just smaller footprint rather macro. It will be something to do with either the values in the sheet or a small difference in your code versus mine I think.

Comment: ok, I will recheck through the code and learn from your template. Appreciate for your solution.Thank

Comment: No problem. Thank so much

Comment: Hi, you unselected as answer. What is missing please?

Comment: Hi @Qharr, thank for remind, i think i have wrongly unclicked the button.

Comment: Hi @Qharr ya, I have addressed the issue based on solution you provided. As what I have seen from some threads, they re-posted the solution based on their code after they have solved their issue. So I just thought I need to re-post the solution based on my question. Really sorry for my mistake. If you dont mind, I have deleted that post as well.

Comment: No worries. It just becomes confusing for future readers if answers don't match with the question. Thank you for being considerate.

Comment: ok.No problem. Thank for the remind. Just trying to contribute some to make this forum great! :)