# VBA: Web scraping and displaying results in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have a VBA code that successfully searches a house on Zillow, however I'm trying to extract the part of the website that shows the status (class="status") and display the results on an excel spreadsheet.

```
Sub getHTMLdocument()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim stat As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "zillow.com/homes"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document
Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("citystatezip")
HTMLInput.Value = "21371 Estepa Circle Huntington Beach"

Set HTMLButtons = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")
HTMLButtons(0).Click

Set stat = HTMLDoc.getElementById("yui_3_18_1_1_1548832597156_4287")
    Debug.Print stat.getAttribute("href")

End Sub
```

Eventually I also want the VBA to pull data from a spreadsheet and load each automatically at the push of a button.

Ex:

111 Main st [Button that loads Zillow for 111]

211 Main st [Button that loads Zillow for 211]

311 Main st [Button that loads Zillow for 311]...

However, I'd really appreciate it if I could at least get it to display the class="status" part on excel

Answer (score 2):

You can use a css class selector

```
HTMDoc.querySelector(".status").innerText
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52570764/6241235) for an example of looping urls.

Comment: Did this answer your question please?